# How to escape comma in string Python 2.7 in a .csv file

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, csv, escaping

I have a string `ven = "the big bad, string"` in a .csv file. I need to escape the `,` character using *Python 2.7*.

Currently I am doing this: `ven = "the big bad\, string"`, but when I run the following command `print ven`, it prints `the big bad\, string` in the terminal.

How do I effectively escape the `,` character from this string within a `.csv` file so if someone were to dl that file and open it in excel it wouldn't screw everything up?

Comment: Are you using `import csv`, or are you constructing the csv files manually?

Comment: @Robᵩ Constructing them manually. To much work to undo it and use import csv. :/

Comment: Why the downvote? What gives?

Comment: Also, it isn't clear from your question whether you are *reading* CSV files or *constructing* CSV files. Nor whether `ven =` is present in the CSV file or merely present in your code. Please read [mcve] and consider creating a short, complete sample program that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're using [the csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), you don't have to do anything. `csv` deals with it for you:

```
import csv

w = csv.writer(open("result.csv","w"))
w.writerow([1,"a","the big bad, string"])
```

result:

```
1,a,"the big bad, string"
```

If, however, you aren't using `import csv`, then you'll want to quote that field:

```
row = [1, "a", "the big bad, string"]
print ','.join('"%s"'%i for i in row)
```

Result:

```
"1","a","the big bad, string"
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped alot.